# Is $K[X]\hookrightarrow K[[X]]$ an epimorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, formal-power-series

Let $K$ be a field and $X$ an indeterminate.

> Is the natural monomorphism $K[X]\hookrightarrow K[[X]]$ an epimorphism?

By *epimorphism* I mean *epimorphism in the category of commutative rings*.

**EDIT.** The question can be spelled out as follows: Are there distinct morphisms from $K[[X]]$ to some commutative ring $A$ which coincide on $K[X]$?

Comment: What is an *epimorphism* exactly ? $K[[x]]$ is the completion of $K[x]$ for the (non-Archimedian) absolute value $|x^Nf(x)| = 2^{-N}$ if $f(0) \ne 0$

Comment: @reuns The inclusion $f:K[X]\to K[[X]]$ is epi if for every two ring homomorphisms $g_1,g_2:K[[X]]\to R$, if $g_1\circ f=g_2\circ f$ then $g_1=g_2$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The map from a Noetherian local ring to its completion is faithfully flat, and a faithfully flat epimorphism is an isomorphism. It follows from this that the map from the localization of $K[X]$ at $(X)$ to $K[[X]]$ is not epi.

Comment: See http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VM and http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00MC

Comment: Is there a straightforward way to extract a concrete counterexample from this?

Comment: +1! Thanks!!! Looks like the perfect answer! But I prefer to wait a bit before accepting it, not to discourage other answers, and also to try to learn the notion of faithful flatness...

Comment: The easy fact that $K[X]\to K[X]_{(X)}$ is an epimorphism is implicit in your answer. Right?

Comment: @Pierre-Yves Gaillard, we have that the inclusion factors as $K[X]\to K[X]_{(X)}\to K[[X]]$, so if the inclusion were epi, $K[X]_{(X)}\to K[[X]]$ would have to be as well.

Comment: @Ennar - Thanks! That's what I meant. (That is, the reader is supposed to check that the first map is an epimorphism.)

Comment: I don't think that's what they're saying, they're saying "If $f\circ g$ is epi, then so is $f$"

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying, @Max. That $K[X]\to K[X]_{(X)}$ is epimorphism establishes the other direction in "if and only if", but is not needed here.

Comment: @Ennar - You're right! I made a confusion. Sorry!

Comment: @Max - You're right! I made a confusion. Sorry!

Comment: @tomasz - If the morphism of commutative rings $A\to B$ is not an epimorphism, this fact is witnessed by the two natural morphisms $B\to B\otimes_AB$.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: I see. That makes sense. I was thinking of something more concrete than that, though.

Answer (score 7):

Let $B$ be a transcendence basis for the field $K((X))$ over $K(X)$ and let $L$ be an algebraic closure of $K((X))$.  Note that any injection from $B$ to itself can be extended to an endomorphism of $L$ over $K(X)$.  There are many such injections, since $B$ is uncountable (see below for a proof).  Restricting these endomorphisms to $K((X))$ gives many different homomorphisms $K((X))\to L$ which all agree on $K[X]$.  Restricting these homomorphisms to $K[[X]]$, we get many different homomorphisms $K[[X]]\to L$ which agree on $K[X]$.  (They are still different since a homomorphism on $K((X))$ is determined by its restriction to $K[[X]]$.)

[There are many other ways you could frame this same idea; for instance you could set it up more like uSir470888's answer.  The point is that it's really easy to define homomorphisms into an algebraically closed field.  In particular, once you're mapping into an algebraically closed field you can forget about whatever rigidity $K[[X]]$ might have had over $K[X]$ and map transcendental elements of $K[[X]]$ to any algebraically independent elements you want.]

---

Here is a proof that $K((X))$ always has uncountable transcendence degree over $K(X)$.  First, we prove a lemma:

> **Lemma**: Let $k$ be a field, let $K$ be a field extension of $k$, and suppose $S\subset k((X))$ is algebraically independent over $k(X)$.  Then $S$ is algebraically independent over $K(X)$, as a subset of $K((X))$.
>
> *Proof*: Suppose some elements $s_1,\dots,s_n \in S$ satisfy $h(s_1,\dots,s_n)=0$, where $h$ is a nonzero polynomial with coefficients in $K[X]$.  For each $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, the $X^m$ term of $h(s_1,\dots,s_n)$ can be written as a polynomial in the coefficients of the $s_i$ (which are certain elements of $k$) and the coefficients of the coefficients of $h$ (each coefficient of $h$ is an element of $K[X]$, and the coefficients of the coefficients of $h$ are elements of $K$).  Moreover, these polynomials are actually linear in the coefficients of the coefficients of $h$.  So to say that $h(s_1,\dots,s_n)=0$ is to say that the coefficients of the coefficients of $h$ satisfy a certain infinite list of linear equations with coefficients in $k$.  But if a system of linear equations in finitely many variables with coefficients in a field $k$ has a nonzero solution in an extension of $k$, it has a nonzero solution in $k$ (this is essentially the fact that the rank of a matrix cannot change if you extend the base field).  This means that we can replace the coefficients of $h$ by polynomials with coefficients in $k$ (which are not all zero) and $h(s_1,\dots,s_n)=0$ will still be true.  This contradicts the assumption that $S$ is algebraically independent over $k(X)$.

Now let $K$ be any field, and let $k$ be any countable subfield of $K$.  Since $k(X)$ is countable and $k((X))$ is uncountable, there exists an uncountable subset $S\subset k((X))$ which is algebraically independent over $k(X)$.  By the Lemma, $S$ is also algebraically independent over $K(X)$ as a subset of $K((X))$.

Comment: Awesome! I wish I could accept several answers! The link http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00MC given by Mariano shows that $A\to\hat A_{\mathfrak m}$ is not an epimorphism (unless it's an isomorphism) if $A$ is local and noetherian. I was wondering if, with your argument, you couldn't show that this is also true if $A$ is a (not necessarily noetherian) domain?

Comment: A variant of my argument shows that if $B$ is any $A$-algebra which has elements which are transcendental over $A$, then $A\to B$ is not an epimorphism.  But I don't believe that $\hat{A}_\mathfrak{m}$ must always have transcendental elements (if it is different from $A$).  For instance, let $A$ be local ring intermediate between $K[X]_{(X)}$ and $K[[X]]$ which contains an entire transcendence basis for $K[[X]]$.  Then if I'm not mistaken, the completion of $A$ will just be $K[[X]]$, which is algebraic over $A$.

Comment: Thank you! I realized that there is an elementary point I don't understand in you answer. You need to know (it seems to me) that the transcendence degree of $K((X))$ over $K(X)$ is at least two. What would be a simple argument to prove this?

Comment: It should not be hard to prove that $\sum_n X^{n!}$ and $\sum_n X^{(n!)!}$ are algebraically independent over $K(X)$--it's the same argument as the proof that $\sum_n 10^{-n!}$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I have added a proof that $K((X))$ has uncountable transcendence degree over $K(X)$ to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still trying to understand this point, but another question occurred to me in the meantime, and I'm so impatient to ask it that I can't wait. Can one summarize your argument as follows? Let $B$ be a domain, let $A$ be a subring, let $L/K$ be the induced extension of fields of fractions. Then, if $A\to B$ is an epimorphism, so is $K\to L$. And what you do is proving that $K(X)\to K((X))$ is *not* an epimorphism.

Comment: Yeah, that's the structure of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

[Still checking if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are well defined. Let me know if you find something that doesn't. I changed the target ring to a larger one because I needed space for values on algebraic elements once I force a definition on a transcendental one.]

Let $R$ be the ring of power series on $X$ that are **algebraic** over the ring of fractions over $K$. This is $R$ consists of all power series $h$ such that there is a polynomial $p(Y)=a_0+a_1Y+...+a_nY^n$ with $a_i$ rational functions over $K$ with denominators that don't vanish at $X=0$, such that $p(h)=0$.

We need to construct two different homomorphisms $g_1,g_2$ from $K[[X]]$ to $R$ such that they coincide on the polynomials. That way $g_1\circ i=g_2\circ i$ for the inclusion $i:K[X]\to K[[X]]$ but $g_1\neq g_2$. Showing that $i$ is not an epimorphism.

Define $g_i(s)=s$ for $s\in R \subset K[[X]]$, $i=1,2$.

Now define $g_1(e^X)=1$ and $g_2(e^X)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}X^n=(1-X)^{-1}$. In particular $g_1(e^X)=1\neq (1-X)^{-1}=g_2(e^X)$. This defines $g_1,g_2$ on the sub-ring of $K[[X]]$ generated by $R$ and powers of $e^{nX}$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, which are the elements of the form $\sum_{n=-N}^{N}e^{nX}a_n$ for $a_n\in R$. Observe how the transcendence of $e^X$ implies that each element of this sub-ring has a unique expression in this form. Their images by $g_1,g_2$ are $\sum_{n=-N}^{N}a_n$ and $\sum_{n=-N}^{N}(1-X)^{-n}a_n$ respectively.

We have $g_1,g_2$ defined in a larger sub-ring $R_{1}$. We still need to define them appropriately on the elements of $K[[X]]$ that are algebraic over $R_1$.

Assume $Y\in K[[X]]$ is algebraic over $R_{1}$. Then there is a polynomial $p(Z)=a_0+a_1Z+...+a_nZ^n$ with coefficients $a_i\in R_1$ such that $p(Y)=0$.
We need to define $g_1,g_2$ on $Y$ to be a solution of $0=g_i(a_0)+g_i(a_1)Z+...+g_i(a_n)Z^n$, respectively. In $R$ we have solutions of $0=g_i(a_0)+g_i(a_1)Z+...+g_i(a_n)Z^n$. So, we can send $Y$ to one of those solutions. This extends $g_1,g_2$ to a larger sub-ring $R_2$ of elements of $K[[X]]$ algebraic over $R_1$.

We can again pick an element of $K[[X]]$ transcendental over $R_2$. Defining their images in $R$ to be $1$ or $(1-X)^{-1}$ we can extend $g_1,g_2$ again and again to homomorphisms on ever larger subrings of $K[[X]]$.

The end results will be ring homomorphism that are different at $e^X$ but equal on the polynomials.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to understand your answer, but I'm very slow. (I changed the index $K$ to $N$ in your post, to avoid a clash with the field $K$.)

Comment: Exp(-X) is not in the ring generated by R and exp(X), No?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Fixed that. I meant generated by the powers of $e^X$.

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of headaches by just taking your target to be some algebraically closed field containing $K[[X]]$; see my answer.